# Fire same Task after 1 minute

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asynchronous

I am storing incoming data into SQL server database
In storing process assigning group Id for 3000 records

I have written windows application that check new data is incoming into the database. first checking number of groups created while storing data and staring task same as number of groups

For that I written `async Task` and within I am checking new groups 
Also written another method that send data to application without wait for complition of task. `using Task.Factory.StartNew()` I starting new task for each group

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Task _proccessSmsQueueTask;
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;
    private ManualResetEvent _shutdownEvent;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _shutdownEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _proccessSmsQueueTask = Task.Run(() => DoWorkAsync(_cancellationTokenSource.Token));

    }

    public async Task DoWorkAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        while (!_shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0))
        {

            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection("ServerName"))
                {

                    try
                    {
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        SqlCommand cmd = null;
                        string query = "dbo.proc_checkgrp";
                        con1.Open();
                        cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con1);
                        cmd.CommandText = query;
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Connection = con1;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mode", 2);
                        cmd.CommandTimeout = 10000;
                        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                        da.Fill(dt);
                        con1.Close();



                        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {

                            SqlCommand cmd1 = null;
                            string query1 = "dbo.proc_checkgrp_updateasUsed";
                            con1.Open();
                            cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query1, con1);
                            cmd1.CommandText = query;
                            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            cmd1.Connection = con1;
                            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grpId", dt.Rows[i]["groupId"].ToString());
                            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mode", 8);
                            cmd1.CommandTimeout = 1000;
                            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            con1.Close();



                            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => send(dt.Rows[i]["groupId"].ToString()),
                                    CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default);
                        }
                    }

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }

            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60), token);
        }
    }


    public void send(string grpid)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection("Servername"))
        {

            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = null;
                string query = "dbo.proc_insett";
                con1.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con1);
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Connection = con1;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grpId", grpid);
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 10000;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con1.Close();

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me help you... putting the description first makes the question look better on the list and it's easier to read too. I corrected the copy/paste indentation.

Comment: Which part of your code `fires same Task after 1 minute`? I'm not seeing it.

Comment: DoWorkAsync fire after 1 minute

Answer (score 5):

## Naming

> ```
> public async Task DoWorkAsync(CancellationToken token)
> ```

*DoWorkAsync* is not a very expressive name. You should use a name that is more specific about what the method is doing.

---

## Disposing

You know the `using` statement but you are not using it for all disposable types in your code. There are more like the cancellation source, the sql data adapter or the sql command.

---

## Joining

> ```
> DataTable dt = new DataTable();
> SqlCommand cmd = null;
> string query = "dbo.proc_checkgrp";
> con1.Open();
> cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con1);
> cmd.CommandText = query;
> cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
> cmd.Connection = con1;
> cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mode", 2);
> cmd.CommandTimeout = 10000;
> SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
> da.Fill(dt);
> con1.Close();
>
>
>
> for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
> {
>
>   SqlCommand cmd1 = null;
>   string query1 = "dbo.proc_checkgrp_updateasUsed";
>   con1.Open();
>   cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query1, con1);
>   cmd1.CommandText = query;
>   cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
>   cmd1.Connection = con1;
>   cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grpId", dt.Rows[i]["groupId"].ToString());
>   cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mode", 8);
>   cmd1.CommandTimeout = 1000;
>   cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
>   con1.Close();
> ```

You first get something from a database to use this result to do something else with the database. This looks like it should be a join in a store procedure not not a loop.

Answer (score 4):

Don't open and close the connection in the loop?  Open, loop, then close.

You don't need a DataTable here.  Use a DataReader and process as you go.

Open catch blocks are not a good practice.

You are duplicating the CommnadText

.NET SQL has asynch  [Command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh223678.aspx).  Use that but I am surprised you you need it here.

You don't need the first try - using statement is not likely to fail

Something like this
You may need two connections - not sure if you can have two commands on the same connnection
Syntax from memory so there will be mistakes

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("ServerName"))
{
    try
    {
       con.Open();
       using (SqlCommand cmd1 = con.CreateCommand())
       using (SqlCommand cmd2 = con.CreateCommand())
       using (SqlCommand cmd3 = con.CreateCommand())  
       {
           cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
           cmd1.CommandText = "dbo.proc_checkgrp";           
           cmd1.CommandTimeout = 10000; 
           cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grpId", grpid);

           cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
           cmd2.CommandText = "dbo.proc_checkgrp_updateasUsed";
           cmd2.CommandTimeout = 10000;
           SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter(@grpId, SqlDbType.VarChar);
           cmd2.Parameters.Add(param1); 
           cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mode", 8); 

           cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
           cmd3.CommandText = "dbo.proc_insett";
           cmd3.CommandTimeout = 10000;
           SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter("@grpId"SqlDbType.VarChar);
           cmd3.Parameters.Add(param2); 

           using (SQLdataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
           {
               while (dr.Read())
               {
                   param1.value = dr.GetSting(0);
                   cmd2.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

                   param2.value = dr.GetSting(0);
                   cmd3.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
               }
           }   
        }      
    }    
}
```

Comment: In second procedure proc_checkgrp_updateasUsed I am updating insert filed after status change I am insert that value is this work here